# Instance of local time variable in js

Tags: javascript

I am using a build variable which gives current date and time

```
let build =  new Date().toLocaleDateString() + "_" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
```

For an automation run, anywhere I call this variable, the value changes.

But I need for an automation run, the build value should be same. Again i trigger a second run, at that time build should fetch new value, how is that possible ?

Comment: `new Date()` of js gives you client's Date. So it would be different if a client has different address. Consider getting it from server or synchronize your client's time with some NTP server

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. What I think you want is for the result stored in your build variable to change on each consequent run but remain the same while your run / build is in progress?

Comment: @EugenTimm - Thats correct

Answer (score 0):

```js
let build =  new Date().toLocaleDateString() + "_" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

localStorage.build = build; 

console.log(localStorage.build);
```

You can calculate value once and store somewhere like localStorage and read it from there.

> PS : localStorage will not work in `RUN CODE SNIPPET` due to
>   cross-origin issues.

Comment: I am getting error that localStorage is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Everytime the script runs, it assigns a new time stamp to the build variable.
You need to create the time stamp in some outside script, which only runs once and assign the value to a variable, which you can use accross your application.

For eg:

```
(function createTimestamp(){
    build = new Date().toLocaleDateString() + "_" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
})()
```

Here `build` is global variable which you can use across the script.